# Show calculated results from a SharePoint list

Tags: list

I have a list in which users can register some distances. On a page somewhere else on the SharePoint site I would like to show the total distance based on the list and compare that to a goal distance.

Which method would you use and how would you make it nice looking/appealing? There will probably be 2-3 values that should be shown on the page (also calculated from a list).

Comment: Just to clarify: I do not want to show the list itself, I want to show some calculated data. e.g. Sum of registered distances based on the data from the data list. Any smart howto's on that? I have (from the answers) created a CQWP and it shows the list data fine, but thats not the goal...

Comment: Even though you are saying you don't want to "show the list itself", you want to show calculations based on the list data.  DVWPs are excellent for that.  A CQWP will be too restrictive, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No shortage of responses here! (And thanks, Jaap for mentioning my [jQuery Library for SharePoint Web Services](http://spservices.codeplex.com) as an option.)

I would probably start with a Data View Web Part (DVWP) because I take the "on a page somewhere else on the SharePoint site" part of your question as meaning that the list is in a different site in the Site Collection than where you would like to display it.  (The terms site/web/Site Collection/subsite/etc. are used inconsistently even by Microsoft and even across access methods!)

Comment: when **wouldnt** you start with a DVWP ;-D JK

Comment: Your assumption on the location of the list is correct :o) I have a site in the collection for data (various lists) and the some portal display pages where various data are shown, partly based on the data site etc.

Comment: Anders: When wouldn't I start with a DVWP? When I wasn't using SharePoint. We don't call it the Swiss Army Knife of Web Parts for nothing!

Comment: Got a little stuck: How to write XSLT for the DVWP, so that I get the sum of values in the "Distance" column? Preferably it should be able to skip empty values.
I tried using this: /dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Distance as input for the sum, but that did not work... any clues?

Comment: I added what I think is the answer to this question on your new thread asking about this.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use jQuery and the SharePoint web services.

Check out Marc D Anderson's [jQuery Library for SharePoint Web Services](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) for a quick and easy way to develop against the SP web services using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The spec is a bit thin, but AFAICS you should be able to do this with OOTB web parts like Content Query Web Part.

hth
Anders Rask

Some references on CQWP:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee413993.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447557.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981241.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms497457.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can display any list as a web part on any page and choose which columns from the list you wan to see. To see this in action, on the default page, click Site Actions, Edit Page, Add Web Part, choose any of the web parts from the Lists and Libraries section, then Edit the Current View (in the web part's task pane). You could put the goals into a separate column in the same list OR if you have MOSS Enterprise Edition you can use the KPI web parts to manage your goals OR you can do something like what is shown at http://www.pathtosharepoint.com/Pages/ProgramsDashboard.aspx. Lots of choices

Answer (score 0):

Another method (if you are running MOSS) would be to create a KPI list. Each item in this list is an indicator: a calculation from another data source with thresholds to trigger goals and warnings. For Total Distance, you would add an indicator that pulls from the list that registers distance and sums that distance. When you click on the title link of this indicator, it will show a page that includes the Total Distance.

After you have all of your indicators, you could create a page with KPI Detail web parts for each indicator you would like to show. That way, you could include all your indicators on one page.

Here is a step-by-step: [Create and publish Key Performance Indicators](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA100800271033.aspx)

Comment: Does not have access to enterprise features in this case...